# Oracle SQL Developer Data Modeler: How to Search for a Table and Show in the Diagram

Tags: database

In the [Oracle SQL Developer Data Modeler 4.0](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/datamodeler/downloads/datamodeler-4ea-downloads-1988443.html), there is find functionality. It's icon is the binoculars in the top right corner.

When we use that find operation, we receive a list view of results that fit the search. That's helpful. It doesn't help me find the entity's location in the diagram.

How can we find the location of the entity in the diagram? I.e. I would like a find option that let's me jump to any table and/or column on the table by name.

Answer (score 2):

There is a section below the result list that when you click one result in the result list, it shows the diagram where that result appears. If you double click it, it will show the location in the diagram.